# JavaScript objects and setting variables

Tags: javascript, oop

I have a object like this:

```
var MyObject = {
    item_1: 15000,
    item_2: new Array(),
    item_3: new Array(),
    init : function() {

    }
}
```

I know there is a way to cycle through the variables set in the init function check to see if that item is the then set value. If not, the make one.

So when I type something like this

```
MyObject.init({
    item_1: 200,
    item_2:{
        item_a: "value"
    },
    item_3:{
        item_y:"value",
        item_z:"value"
    }
});
```

then cycle through the argument and then set the values.

Comment: `for..in` loop seems like the best option.

Comment: how would i do that JS is new to me

Comment: Well, the first step would be to [Google `javascript for in loop`](http://google.com/search?q=javascript+for+in+loop) - the first result should be [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) - MDN is one of the best resources for JavaScript stuff. Just be careful, there are bad ones out there too, like W3Schools.

Comment: @Kolink -- And unfortunately W3Schools appears on most top searches :\

Comment: The title and the question are rather poor.
What exactly is your question?
What do you have problems with?

Comment: @PointedEars `hasOwnProperty` is only needed if you extend the `Object` prototype, which you shouldn't be doing anyway...

Comment: @Kolink (Oh great, is there censorship of correct corrections at Stack Overflow now?) No, it is always needed if you want to consider only *own* (*enumerable*) properties and cannot use ES5's `Object.keys()` or `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`.

Comment: @PointedEars I have never used `hasOwnProperty`, never had any issues.

Comment: @Kolink Then you have been lucky. Some people, myself included, think that augmenting some prototype objects, like that referred by `Array.prototype`, are worth extending if that provides for more uniform or elegant code. But then you will have to take precautions for efficient `for…in` iteration because those user-defined properties are usually enumerable (the features to make them not enumerable were introduced with ES 5), and in any case `for…in` considers *inherited* enumerable properties even if they are not user-defined. Conforming implementations *may* provide additional properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, your syntax is wrong.

```
var = MyObject{}
```

should be:

```
var MyObject = {}
```

Second, you can't have spaces in your keys (unless you enclose the key in quotes), so this:

```
item 1 : 15000,
...
```

Should be:

```
item_1: 15000,
...
```

(But it looks like someone fixed that for you in an edit.)

Third, you are over-complicating this. If you really want to *cycle* though the properties inside your object, you can do this:

```
for (key in MyObject){
    if (MyObject.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        if (key == item_1){
            key = 200;
        }
    }
}
```

But as you can see, if you use a loop you have to do a check against each key to make sure you get the right value assigned to the right key. This is because JavaScript does not guarantee the order in which properties are returned to you.

You can do this however:

```
var MyObject = {
    item_1: 15000,
    item_2: new Array(),
    item_3: new Array(),
    init : function(item_1,item_2, item_3){
        item_1 = item_1;
        item_2 = item_2;
        item_3 = item_3;
    }
}
```

Then do this:

```
MyObjectMyObject.init(
   item_1 = 200, 
   item_2 = {item_a: "value"}, 
   item_3 = {item_y:"value", item_z:"value"}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a variable amount of arguments, you can access them with the [arguments object](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/loop-parameters-passed-javascript-function/) (tutorial in link), you can loop through all of them with a [for..in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) like in the comments.

Comment: At the same time it might be worth to mention that the arguments object is not available in strict mode. See http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.6 http://www.jslint.com/ and http://www.jshint.com/